# Bracket Order With Multiple Target Exits Using ib_insync

Tags: python-3.x, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I am trying to create a bracket order that that will exit 1/2 the position at target 1 and the 2nd half at target 2. I am able to generate the orders, however, the quantity for both of the targets is the entire position amount rather than 1/2. For instance, when placing an order to buy 200 SPY the profit taking orders should have a quantity of 100 each, not 200. However, when I run my code this is the order displayed in TWS:

[image]

I am running:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, May  6 2020, 09:02:42) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
ib_insync 0.9.61
TWS Build 979.4t
Java Version: 1.8.0_152, OS: Windows 10 (amd64, 10.0)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Please run this code to reproduce the situation:

```
from ib_insync import *
import time
from typing import NamedTuple

class BracketOrderTwoTargets(NamedTuple):
    parent: Order
    takeProfit: Order
    takeProfit2: Order
    stopLoss: Order

#modified from this post, https://groups.io/g/insync/message/3135
def bracketStopLimitOrderTwoTargets(
        action: str, quantity: float, stopPrice: float,
        limitPrice: float, takeProfitPrice1: float, takeProfitPrice2: float,
        stopLossPrice: float, **kwargs) -> BracketOrderTwoTargets:
    """
    Create a limit order that is bracketed by 2 take-profit orders and
    a stop-loss order. Submit the bracket like:

    Args:
        action: 'BUY' or 'SELL'.
        quantity: Size of order.
        stopPrice: Stop Price for stopLimit entry order
        limitPrice: Limit price of entry order.
        takeProfitPrice1: 1st Limit price of profit order.
        takeProfitPrice2: 2nd Limit price of profit order.
        stopLossPrice: Stop price of loss order.
        StopLimitOrder(action, totalQuantity, lmtPrice, stopPrice, **kwargs)
    """
    assert action in ('BUY', 'SELL')
    reverseAction = 'BUY' if action == 'SELL' else 'SELL'
    parent = StopLimitOrder(
        action, quantity, limitPrice, stopPrice,
        orderId=ib.client.getReqId(),
        transmit=False,
        outsideRth=True,
        **kwargs)
    takeProfit1 = LimitOrder(
        action=reverseAction, totalQuantity=quantity/2, lmtPrice=takeProfitPrice1,
        orderId=ib.client.getReqId(),
        transmit=False,
        parentId=parent.orderId,
        outsideRth=True,
        **kwargs)
    takeProfit2 = LimitOrder(
        action=reverseAction, totalQuantity=quantity/2, lmtPrice=takeProfitPrice2,
        orderId=ib.client.getReqId(),
        transmit=False,
        parentId=parent.orderId,
        outsideRth=True,
        **kwargs)
    stopLoss = StopOrder(
        reverseAction, quantity, stopLossPrice,
        orderId=ib.client.getReqId(),
        transmit=True,
        parentId=parent.orderId,
        outsideRth = True,
        **kwargs)
    return BracketOrderTwoTargets(parent, takeProfit1, takeProfit2, stopLoss)


ib = IB()
client_id = int(time.time())  # gets second since epoch. No need for the milliseconds, so round to int
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=client_id, timeout=10)

contract = Stock('SPY', exchange='SMART', currency='USD')
[ticker] = ib.reqTickers(contract)
contract_price = ticker.marketPrice()

high_bracket = bracketStopLimitOrderTwoTargets(action='BUY', quantity=200, stopPrice=contract_price+18,
                                               limitPrice=contract_price+20,
                                               takeProfitPrice1=contract_price+30,
                                               takeProfitPrice2=contract_price+45,
                                               stopLossPrice=contract_price-5)

for order in high_bracket:
    order_res = ib.placeOrder(contract=contract, order=order)
    print(order_res)
```

Comment: Maybe read this thread, https://groups.io/g/twsapi/message/44507

Comment: @mks212, have you managed to solve this, please?

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk, no I haven't. I switched the trading strategy and I'm no longer using IB.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to do it is using the scale fields attached to the profit taker. I dont know what the API looks like, but check it out in the TWS ui first. In the UI, you will see - Initial component, scale component and Scale price. You can then have the initial component of 100, and if you want the subsequent lots to be different, specify that size in the scale component.